# c++ vector multiple values

Tags: c++, stdvector

I am new to c++, but have half a year of work experience with Java se/ee7.

I am wondering how to put 3 values into `vector<string>`
example: `vector<string, string, string>` or just `vector<string, string>`
to avoid of usage of 3 vectors.

```
vector<string> questions;
vector<string> answers;
vector<string> right_answer;

questions.push_back("Who is the manufacturer of Mustang?");
answers.push_back("1. Porche\n2. Ford \n3. Toyota");
right_answer.push_back("2");

questions.push_back("Who is the manufacturer of Corvette?");
answers.push_back("1. Porche\n2. Ford \n3. Toyota \n4. Chevrolette");
right_answer.push_back("4");


for (int i = 0; i < questions.size(); i++) {
    println(questions[i]);
    println(answers[i]);

    if (readInput() == right_answer[i]) {
        println("Good Answer.");
    } else {
        println("You lost. Do you want to retry? y/n");
        if(readInput() == "n"){
            break;
        }else{
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to use something like `questions[i][0]  questions[i][1] questions[i][3]` if it is possible.

Comment: C++ is very much unlike Java. Don't fall into the trap of thinking things are similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not having a structure like:

```
struct question_data {
    std::string question;
    std::string answers; // this should probably be a vector<string>
    std::string correct_answer;
};
```

and then:

```
std::vector<question_data> questions;
...
for (int i = 0; i < questions.size(); i++) { // I would personally use iterator
    println(questions[i].question);
    println(questions[i].answers);

    if (readInput() == questions[i].correct_answer) ...
}
```

Comment: Thankyou, i am started with c++ today, i never heard about struct, so i wil ltry this

Comment: good luck with your c++ efforts. it is complex but strangely rewarding :)  `struct` is like `class`, with the difference that members are `public` by default, so one line less to write in this example :). Feel free to use class instead of struct

Comment: you understand-ed me right, it works perfectly. thankyou again.

Answer (score 8):

You can have a `struct` and store objects of it in the `vector`:

```
struct question
{
    std::string title;
    std::string choices;
    std::string answer;
};

// ...

question q = {"This is a question", "Choice a\nChoice b", "Choice a"};
std::vector<question> questions;
questions.push_back(q);
```

And then you would use `questions[0].title` or `questions[0].answer`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you wanted to do in modern C++.

You can use a tuple like:

```
std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, std::string>> vec;
std::tuple<std::string, std::string> some_tuple;
some_tuple = std::make_tuple("some", "strings");
vec.push_back(some_tuple);
```

You can use std::tie to later read it.